# How to track network activty at router level?

Tags: networking, router, dns, port-forwarding, network-traffic

Is it possible to track visited URL's on a home network, at *"router level"* - so setup is not required for on each individual device? (other than buying another router?)

- Most routers have a "logging" option, but my `Hitron CGNM-2250` does not (or rather, I assume it did but was disabled by the ISP who provided it).
- I tried OpenDNS but its reporting is limited initial domain lookup, and has no detail like urls or time.

I have an **unused laptop** sitting here; I was thinking maybe the traffic could be forwarded through there and somehow tracked (make it a DSN and point the router to it? Port forwarding? UPNP, etc?) but I don't know if that's even possible.

Note that I'm **not** trying to block traffic; **I only need to *report on it***.

Thoughts? Thx!

Comment: This takes a bit more than a single post to discuss all the intricacies of how this can be done. Long story short, HTTPS traffic is encrypted. You wont be able to see more than a “DNS” request anyways. Being most sites use HTTPS this is all you’re going to see. If you want to get more details you’ll need to create a CA and install a certificate on each device to be monitored. This is typically done as one of the configuration steps when installing an actual UTM device. If your router doesn’t have these features then you cant use it.

Answer (score 0):

I know on netgear routers they show most of the IP's you visit but not the website name like www.cnn.com for example.  I don't know if Netgear or others have the feature to actually log every site you visit.

Most routers have some sort of software program, I don't know if it is based at the router or on your hard drive. know with netgear you can get additional software, but I don't think it is a router based or software based tracking.

Have you gone through your router settings including advanced/admin only or other special designation saying essentially hope you know what you are doing?  Newer and newer routers will almost certainly add features.  The older the router, the less chance it might have any feature like what you are looking for.

I have a sample link to one of netgear routers to see if it at least gets you going towards the right place
https://kb.netgear.com/24224/How-do-I-view-the-activity-logs-of-my-Nighthawk-router

I am not a rep or comp. for saying Netgear, I just have used their products essentially since they built network equipment that you didn't need to a business check book/balance to buy.

Comment: Unfortunately tjis foes not answer the question as the zOP does not have a.netgear  router - but dont feel to bad as its effectivlt an unanswerable question on this forum as its way to broad.

Comment: I was trying to help out the best I could based on my knowledge in hopes it might point him in the right direction.  I got a -1 by answer.